# Segal's 1999 Stanford lecture notes on TQFT, where to find them?

Tags: reference-request, topological-quantum-field-theory

I am trying to track down a copy of Graeme Segal's 1999 lecture notes on topological field theory. These are sometimes referred to as the "Stanford lectures" or something similar.

For many years these unpublished notes were available at Duke's mathematics website via the link: http://www.cgtp.duke.edu/ITP99/segal/

However this link is now dead. Every reference I have found by googling seems to lead back to this dead link. It would be a tragedy if these lecture notes were lost to the mathematics community. I am hoping that somebody out there has retained a copy.

Comment: @joro has found the lectures note that were at the dead link, but lectures 4 and 6 are missing. I am still wondering if there were ever any notes produced from those missing lectures?

Comment: Chris, archive.org has many snapshots over the years. Check another year on archive.org (possibly the last alive snapshot).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For dead links, sometimes http://archive.org helps.

In this case they might be these:

http://web.archive.org/web/20000901075112/http://www.cgtp.duke.edu/ITP99/segal/

Comment: Check other year on archive.org if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Very nice and helpful command @joro. But, what is the number $2000....$? How can we find it?

Comment: @ShahroozJanbaz: At archive.org you enter the old link and you get the archived link by the system. More precisely, you can go back in time, so there are several archived links.

Comment: @GH from MO, so thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The page you're looking for is a mirror of http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~drm/conferences/ITP99/segal/. Unfortunately, lectures 4 and 6 are missing, as are all the diagrams in lecture 1.