# Zeta-Determinant Theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

[Recently](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/216210/segals-1999-stanford-lecture-notes-on-tqft-where-to-find-them), someone asked on MO about lecture notes from Graeme Segal's "Stanford lectures" on TQFT, and the answer was to check [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20000901075112/http://www.cgtp.duke.edu/ITP99/segal/).

When scrolling over the notes, I stumpled of Prop. 2.8.2 in lecture 2. It says (modulo typos) that if $P$ is a Dirac operator and $S$ is an invertible operator such that $S-\mathrm{id}$ is trace-class, then
$$\det\nolimits_\zeta(PS) = \det(S)\det\nolimits_\zeta(P)),$$
where $\det\nolimits_\zeta$ denotes the zeta-regularized determinant and $\det$ denotes the usual determinant.

However, there are neither references nor proofs there. Does anyone know of a proof?

Answer (score 2):

The mathematics here is definitely out of the realm of my understanding, so hopefully someone who knows this stuff will post a better answer.

I believe that Prop 2.8.2 in Segal's Lecture 2 is more or less Proposition 6.4 in ["Determinants of elliptic pseudo-differential operators" by Kontsevich and Vishik](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9404046).

There seems to be an ample literature on zeta determinants of the Laplacian and Dirac operators so you probably can find other sources as well. For example, I actually first found the paper ["Zeta Determinants on Manifolds with Boundary"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406315) by Scott, which includes a stronger statement as Prop. 2.19.